# Why is .sub changing my original dataframe when I am not even performing any operation on it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is the snippet of my code where I am assigning a dataframe (`df4`) to a new dataframe (`df_output_abs`). Thereafter I am working with the new dataframe where I am trying to find difference for few of the columns. The code is working fine but when I am looking at df4 before and after the `.sub` operation (line 4), `df4` is taking the values of `df_output_abs`. I am not sure what is happening here, could anyone please help me understand? I do not want my `df4` to change.

```
col=df4.columns.difference(['2021/22 Proj.', 'Month'])
df_output_abs=df4
display(df4)
df_output_abs[col]=df_output_abs[col].sub(df3[col])
display(df4)
```

Comment: `df_output_abs=df4` this doesnt say make a seperate copy of d4 and call it df_output_abs. It says point df_output_abs at the same thing that d4 points. So now you have to names that point to the same data. if you change via df_outbout_abs, it will be changing the same data that d4 points to

Comment: For future reference: You can use a limited version of markdown to format your questions and answers quite nicely. [Here's some formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Chris, thanks a lot for your help. The code is working as desired after I have used df4.copy() to make a copy of the dataframe. Is it ok to use df.copy()?

Comment: Thanks Martineau for the formatting tips.